# TypeError: pna.nextTick is not a function using simple-peer in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular6, webrtc, simple-peer

I am using `simple-peer` in `angular 7`

```
async ngOnInit() {
    try {
      if (location.hash === '#init') {
        this.peer = new SimplePeer({
          initiator: location.hash === '#init'
        })
      }
      else {
        this.peer = new SimplePeer()
      }

      this.peer.on('signal', function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      })

      this.peer.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('Received Data: ' + data)
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

When angular compiler comes on this event

```
this.peer.on('data', (data) => {
     console.log('Received Data: ' + data)
})
```

then it throws error

> [image]

When I omit this `event` this error is gone

**Note:** Package versions are as

1. `simple-peer v9.1.2`
2. `NPM v6.5.0`
3. `Node v10.14.2`

Comment: it seems the problem is with node version, which node version?

Comment: @FatemeFazli `Node v10.14.2`

Comment: so try ```$ n lts``` then
```$ npm install -g npm``` then
```$ n stable```

Comment: @FatemeFazli working on `windows`, `$` is not recognized

Comment: don't  type ```$``` just ```n lts``` then ```npm install -g npm``` then ```n stable```

Comment: @FatemeFazli so does the `n` is not recognized :D

Comment: @FatemeFazli by the way, `Node v10.14.2` is `LTS` right now. https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: i mean try to change your node version 10.13 or 10.14.0 and test it.

Comment: I have tested with `node` versions i.e. `10.14.2`, `10.13.0`, `10.12.0`, `10.11.0`, `9.11.2`, `8.14.0` and `8.11.4` but all in vain.

Answer (score 4):

exact same issue solved:

```
npm i -S process, then add this to polyfill.ts:
import * as process from 'process';
window['process'] = process;
```

may also install:

```
npm i -S process-nextick-args
```